# Shadows look bad or not show at all

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

So for 12 hours or so I struggled to solve this problem. Search a lot on google for solutions, tried adjusting things myself, reimported, deleted and **upgraded** to other versions of unity. None seemed to solve my problem.
What i am trying to do is very simple, I have a room with some objects in it and 2 spotlights. One for the sun and one that is supposed to be a light bulb or something.
Soft shadows didn't work at all, only hard shadows did some work, but i think its not perfect. Every object in the scene has cast and receive shadows ticked, i am using Universal Render Pipeline. I can provide any other detail needed to help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.
My settings in the lighting and the settings of the spotlight:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtaWz.png)
And of course the room from the camera view:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKQ4r.png)

Comment: Have you turned "Shadow Display" on in the settings?

Comment: Oh and have you deleted Unity Hub and reinstalled it altogether, although I don't believe that would help.

Comment: @Zaxoosh I think it's turned on. I can't find it. Can you be more specific to where i can find it please? Anyway, i dont think deleting unityhub would help as the problem occurred in both recommended version 2019 and 2020.

Comment: Go to settings under graphics or shades, it should be under there, if not search it under the Unity Help Centre.

Comment: @Zaxoosh i didnt find it there. It was in the universal render pipeline asset. In there, under Lighting dropdown tab, for both Main Light and Addition Lights the setting "Cast Shadows" is checked. Also there, under the Shadows dropdown tab, I have set the "Distance" to 100000 and "Soft Shadows" is ticked.

Comment: Also, my second image shows that there are some kind of shadows casting but they look ugly to me. That's what i am trying to solve :/

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm as stuck as you.

Comment: Have you got any screenshots?

Comment: No problem, what screenshots do you need, i can give you anything.

Comment: Whatever the scene looks like!

Comment: [Here you go](https://imgur.com/a/Dfsg6YA)

Answer (score 0):

In the universal render pipeline asset there is an option for soft shadows at Shadows/Soft Shadows.

Hope this helps.